# Is there complete list of spring boot metrics with short description?

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I briefly looked at [actuator documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics) but I was not able to find a list of metrics.

The most detailed information provided [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.supported.jvm) but I want to have more details:

> **JVM Metrics**
>
> Auto-configuration enables JVM Metrics by using core
> Micrometer classes. JVM metrics are published under the jvm. meter
> name.
>
> The following JVM metrics are provided:
>
> - Various memory and buffer pool details
> - Statistics related to garbage collection
> - Thread utilization
> - The number of classes loaded and unloaded
> - JVM version information
> - JIT compilation time

Is there any place where I can find a full list of supported metrics with short description without starting the application ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of as they aren't Spring Boot metrics. They are metrics from other parts of the Spring portffolio (like Spring MVC, Spring Kafka etc. etc.) which should have that documentation. Next to that the default provided metrics from Micrometer.io are also exported (which are in that documentation).

Comment: @M. Deinum good point.

Speaking about default metrics I tried to find them in micrometer

https://micrometer.io/docs/ref/jvm

But still no list of metrics

Comment: Don't see a comprehensive source, what I suggest is to take a look classes in sprintboot actuator autoconfigure, check the metrics config you are interested, e.g. `JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration` for jvm metrics.

Answer (score 1):

I think the core is using [Prometheus Clieny Java](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/getting-started/metric-types/) implement the OpenMetrics standard

> The Prometheus Java metrics library implements the metric types
> defined in the OpenMetrics standard:

Also it provided special metrics.
[Prometheus client java JVM](https://prometheus.github.io/client_java/instrumentation/jvm/), you can check the classes for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't find an exhaustive list